# Looping into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => System
            [order] => 1
            [icon] => stats.svg
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Multilingual
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Coloring
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Team work
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Tutorials
                )

        )
)
```

I want to loop into this to show the section name and after all the features containing in the following array.

So, this is what I made:

```
foreach ($features as $feature => $info) {
    echo '
        '.$info['name'].'
                <ul class="menu-vertical bullets">
    ';

                foreach (array_values($info) as $i => $key) {
                    echo '
                        <li>'.$key['title'].'</li>
                    ';
                }

    echo '
                </ul>
    ';
}
```

It works except for the first third `<li>` where I have the first char of `name`, `order` and `icon` value.

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In php, `array_values` means all the values of the array. So `array_values($info)` is `array($info['name'], $info['order'], $info['icon'], $info[0], $info[1],  $info[2], $info[3])`

in your example, you can skip the non-integer keys of the `$info` to get your titles:

```
<?php
$features = array();
$info = array();
$info['name'] = 'System';
$info['order'] = 1;
$info['icon'] = 'stats.svg';
$info[] = array('title'=>'Multilingual');
$info[] = array('title'=>'Coloring');
$features[] = $info;

foreach ($features as $feature => $info) {
    echo $info['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<ul class="menu-vertical bullets">' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($info as $k => $item) {
        if(!is_int($k)) continue;
        echo '<li>' . $item['title'] . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

BUT, your original data structure is not well designed and hard to use. For a better design, you can consider the following code, move your items to a sub array of `$info`:

```
<?php
$features = array();
$info = array();
$info['name'] = 'System';
$info['order'] = 1;
$info['icon'] = 'stats.svg';
$info['items'] = array();
$info['items'][] = array('title'=>'Multilingual');
$info['items'][] = array('title'=>'Coloring');
$features[] = $info;

foreach ($features as $feature => $info) {
    echo $info['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<ul class="menu-vertical bullets">' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($info['items'] as $item) {
        echo '<li>' . $item['title'] . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Sample output of the two demos:

```
System
<ul class="menu-vertical bullets">
<li>Multilingual</li>
<li>Coloring</li>
</ul>
```

> It works except for the first third `li` where I have the first char of name, order and icon value. Do you know why ?

Why you see first chars of the values of 'name', 'order', 'icon'? Let see how PHP works.

Take the first loop as an example: `foreach (array_values($info) as $i => $key)`

Then `$i == 0, $key == 'System'`

We know that `$key[0] == 'S', $key[1] == 'y', $key[2] == 's'`, etc.

Then you try to access `$key['title']`, but the string `'title'` is not valid as a string offset, so it is converted to an integer by PHP: `intval('title') == 0`.

Then `$key['title'] == $key[intval('title')] == 'S'`

That's what you see.

Answer (score 0):

array_values return value of array so for info values is name, order, icon, 0, 1, ...

Your values foreach is wrong  if you just want print title you can use:

```
foreach ($features as $feature => $info) {

    echo '
        '.$info['name'].'
            <ul class="menu-vertical bullets">
    ';
    //Remove some keys from info array
    $removeKeys = array('name', 'order', 'icon');
    $arr = $info;
    foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
       unset($arr[$key]);
    }

    foreach (array_values($arr) as $i => $key) {
                echo '
                    <li>'.$key['title'].'</li>
                ';
            }

    echo '
            </ul>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_value()` returns the values of the array, here you will get the value of the array $info and what I understand is that is not what you need. See details for [array_value()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

You can check if the key for the $info is an integer. if yes, echo the title. Give this a try.

```
foreach ($features as $feature => $info) {
    echo $info['name'].'<ul class="menu-vertical bullets">';
    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        if (is_int($key)) {
            echo '<li>'.$key['title'].'</li>';  
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```